# jQuery addClass and removeClass onchange issue

Tags: jquery, css, onchange, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to get jQuery's addClass and removeClass to work in a form select environment with little success.

I want to modify the parent div's class and was trying to pass the ID in the function but all my attempts have been futile. Any direction and assistance would be much appreciated.

```
<div id="MaxAge" class="SearchFormStyle">
                <select name="maxage" onchange="addClass(MaxAge);">
                    <option value="0">Age</option>
                    <option value="1" >1 Year Old</option>
                    <option value="2" >2 Years Old</option>
                </select>
                    <span class="ThisValue">
                        <a href="#" onclick="RemoveClass(MaxAge)">VALUE ENTERED HERE</a>
                    </span>
                </div>

<script>
    function addClass (id) { 
        div = "#" + id; 
        $(div).addClass("InputSet"); 
    }
    function RemoveClass (id) { 
        div = "#" + id; 
        $(div).removeClass("InputSet"); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, what exactly is the desired effect?

Comment: Example effect : http://www.autotrader.co.uk/

On the Car Search, select a Max Price to see the effect.

Answer (score 3):

`addClass(MaxAge)` will pass the *value of the variable* `MaxAge` to `addClass`, not the string `'MaxAge'`.

Besides, you really should use jQuery to bind event handlers instead of inline event handlers:

```
$("select[name='maxage']").change(function() {
    addClass('MaxAge');
});

$('.ThisValue a').click(function(event) {
    RemoveClass('MaxAge');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

To learn more about event handlers, I recommend to read the [articles at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

---

There are also other problems, like the `div` variable in `addClass` and `RemoveClass` being *global*. Don't forget `var` when you are declaring variables. Also the naming of the function is inconsistent `add` vs `Remove`.

The [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) is very good for learning the JavaScript basics.

Answer (score 0):

you're almost doing it the right way. Here's what I would do (with some comments for you)

```
// onchange event of the selectbox with id = maxage
$("#maxage").change(function() {
    $("#MaxAge").addClass("InputSet");
});

// the click event for the a element within span with class ThisValue
$("span.ThisValue a").click(function(e) {
    // prevent doing default behaviour like going to another location...
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#MaxAge").removeClass("InputSet");
});
```

Comment: There is about 10 select's within the form I have so it would be easier to have a single function that can handle all the selects rather than a function for each Element ID. 

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You're never instantiating the div variable.

Try this:

```
var div = "#" + id;
```

Comment: Thanks but this had no effect